# Can't update an table's column but works after using update sql query in phpmyadmin

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

When a user tries to update their settings, I inserted into my audit log table called `userUpdateLog`and it calls a before insert trigger to insert into `userProfiles` and `users` based off the columns insert into their respective table.

But for an column, `nickName` that I added after the `userProfiles` table was created and have data, it doesn't update via trigger using the query

```
UPDATE userProfiles 
   SET nickName = NEW.newNickName 
 WHERE userID = NEW.userID
```

but when I execute the query in phpmyadmin with written values

```
UPDATE userProfiles 
   SET nickName = 'random' 
 WHERE userID = 2
```

it works and after having data in the column for that specific row, the trigger works and was able to update for that row after inserting into `userUpdateLog` and the triggers executes,

the other rows encounter the same issue until I insert manually via phpmyadmin.

What is the cause of this issue that requires an manually insert via phpmyadmin to work?

```sql
CREATE TABLE `userUpdateLog` (
  `userUpdateLogID` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `userID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updateDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `newUserName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `newEmail` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `newNickName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `newFirstName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `newLastName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oldUserName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oldEmail` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oldNickName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oldFirstName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oldLastName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `usersUpdate_bi` BEFORE INSERT ON `userUpdateLog` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET @userName = (SELECT userName FROM users WHERE userID = NEW.userID);
    SET @email = (SELECT email FROM users WHERE userID = NEW.userID);
    SET @firstName = (SELECT firstName FROM users WHERE userID = NEW.userID);
    SET @lastName = (SELECT lastName FROM users WHERE userID = NEW.userID);
    SET @nickName = (SELECT nickName FROM userProfiles WHERE userID = NEW.userID);
    SET NEW.oldUserName = @userName;
    SET NEW.oldEmail = @email;
    SET NEW.oldFirstName = @firstName;
    SET NEW.oldLastName = @lastName; 
    SET NEW.oldNickName = @nickName;
    IF NEW.newUserName IS NOT NULL AND NEW.newUserName <> NEW.oldUserName THEN
        UPDATE users 
        SET userName = NEW.newUserName 
        WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.newEmail IS NOT NULL AND NEW.newEmail <> NEW.oldEmail THEN
        UPDATE users 
        SET email = NEW.newEmail 
        WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.newFirstName IS NOT NULL AND NEW.newFirstName <> NEW.oldFirstName THEN
        UPDATE users 
        SET firstName = NEW.newFirstName 
        WHERE userID = NEW.userID; 
    END IF;
    IF NEW.newLastName IS NOT NULL AND NEW.newLastName <> NEW.oldLastName THEN
        UPDATE users 
        SET lastName = NEW.newLastName 
        WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.newNickName IS NOT NULL AND NEW.newNickName <> NEW.oldNickName THEN
        UPDATE userProfiles SET nickName = NEW.newNickName 
        WHERE userID = NEW.userID;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CREATE TABLE `userProfiles` (
  `profileID` int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `imgName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nickName` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aboutUser` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `genderID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `bDay` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `favCard` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `userID` int(11) PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `userName` varchar(128) UNIQUE KEY NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) UNIQUE KEY NOT NULL,
  `pwd` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `loginDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `userCreate` AFTER INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
INSERT INTO userProfiles (userID) VALUES(NEW.userID);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Is there something that I need to do after alter table add column etc.. to reload/refresh the tables so `UPDATE userProfiles SET nickName = NEW.newNickName WHERE userID = NEW.userID` query will work in php file or  in triggers. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I just added a new column to the `userProfiles` table and I am unable to add values/input into that column but any column was defined upon creation of the table works.

**UPDATE - 2** I created a new table, using the same columns, fks, and all called `usersProfiles` and the table did not update aswell, until I edited the column via phpmyadmin. Also I noticed when I simulate query in phpmyadmin it says `matched 0 row`, but query worked afterwords upon execute.

Would having 18 tables in the database be the issue? Any help or tips to find the error/issue would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solutions but I found a workaround,

I changed the `nickName` column from:

```sql
ALTER TABLE userProfiles 
CHANGE 'nickName' 'nickName' varchar(128) 
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci 
DEFAULT NULL;
```

to:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `userProfiles` 
CHANGE `nickName` `nickName` VARCHAR(128) 
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci 
NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A';
```

then the columns work and any new row inserted as well, but if I change it back to default null then it glitches as stated in my post.